# CSS bug after embedding Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have a problem where my page formatting is going haywire on only one page that has Google maps embedded in.

Bugs change on different browsers but include Font sizes(FF), moved boxes(FF), drop down menus wont work(IE).

What can I do to solve this problem.

Thanks

Edit: screenshot of my problem.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkqv4.png

Comment: Do you have link or something, we cant figure what's the problem from your description

Comment: Yer sorry, here is a screenshot of my problem. http://i.imgur.com/h79rz.png

Comment: Check your html code in a validator, to see if you've got some non-closed tag on this page.

Comment: running it through netbeans and also firebug and no errors occur.

Comment: We need some code so that we can see what's happening. Or a link as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the file headers where inconsistent and it wasn't calling the required xml files, it wasn't me who did this. Also certain CSS tables where not inheriting as they should of causing certain font sizes and alignments to be messed up.